# Android, Actionbar tabs converted to drop-down menu

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I use actionBar tab navigation (using ActionBarSherlock), and according to The Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)

> Note: In some cases, the Android system will show your action bar tabs as a drop-down list in order to ensure the best fit in the action bar.

When this happens, the icons of the drop-down items are chosen automatically to be the unselected icons of the tabs.

i.e. `<item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/dimmed_pic"/>`

So, How can I show different icons when my tabs are shown as a drop-down list??